# funcion effects de los input signal solo detecta el cambio una vez en angular 17.1

Tags: angular

Tengo una función muy sencilla para probar los input signal, el tóma bien los cambios pero no realiza la funcion que quiero cuando surge un cambio, lo probé con un simple log pero lo imprime una sola vez.

```
export class PrintComponent {
  data$ = input<any[]>([],{})
  constructor(){
    effect(() => {
      console.log(this.data$());
    });
  }
}
```

Sé que detecta los cambios porque cuando miro el log despues de varios cambios se puede ver los datos agregados

```
[{}]
> {date: "2024-01-01 06:00:00", document:"1096246802", names:"Gustavo Adolfo Gómez sandoval"}
> {date: "2024-01-01 06:00:00", document:"1096246802", names:"Gustavo Adolfo Gómez sandoval"}
> {date: "2024-01-01 06:00:00", document:"1096246802", names:"Gustavo Adolfo Gómez sandoval"}
```

sin embargo la acción esperada es que en cada cambio imprima el array con toda la data

Comment: No he trabajado mucho con signals pero creo que el comportamiento por defecto es emitir el valor que le pasas, no concatenar... Si quieres que concatene todos los valores en un único array por lo que veo en la [documentación](https://angular.io/guide/signals) tendrás que hacer algo similar a `data$.update((value) => [...value, newObject]);`. Es decir, tienes que mantener tú el array